# Cannot find the tensor which resulted in TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am playing with a simple Domain-Adversarial Neural Networks (DANN) but got a confusing Error:
`TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type int32 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.`

The relevant code:

```
def train_DANN(lamda,X_train0, X_test0,X_train1, X_test1, y_train0, y_test0, y_train1, y_test1):
    label_preds_head_name = 'label_preds'
    domain1_preds_head_name = 'domain1_preds'
    inputs        = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(X_train0.shape[1],))
    hidden1       = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu')(inputs)
    hidden2       = tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='relu')(hidden1)
    hidden3       = tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='relu')(hidden2)
    label_preds   = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name=label_preds_head_name)(hidden3)

    label_prediction_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        inputs  = inputs,
        outputs = label_preds,
        name    = 'classification_model')
    label_prediction_model.summary()
    
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    lr_metric = get_lr_metric(optimizer)
    label_prediction_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                               loss='binary_crossentropy',
                               metrics=['AUC',lr_metric])

    nom_fit = label_prediction_model.fit(x = X_train0,
                                     y = y_train0,
                                     epochs = num_epoch,
                                     validation_data = (X_test0, y_test0),
                                     callbacks = [#SensitivitySpecificityCallback(),
                               tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lr_exp_decay)])

    d1_as_nom_fit = label_prediction_model.fit(x = X_train1,
                                           y = y_train1,
                                           epochs = num_epoch,
                                           validation_data = (X_test1, y_test1),
                                           callbacks = [#SensitivitySpecificityCallback(),
                               tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lr_exp_decay)])


    @tf.custom_gradient
    def reverse_gradient(x, hp_lambda):
        # Feed-forward operation:
        y = tf.identity(x)
        # Back-propagation/gradient-computing operation:
        def _flip_gradient(dy):
            # Since the decorated function 'reverse_gradient()' actually has 2 inputs
            # (counting 'hp_lambda'), we have to return the gradient for each -- but
            # anyway, the derivative wrt 'hp_lambda' is null:
            return tf.math.negative(dy) * hp_lambda, tf.constant(0.)
        return y, _flip_gradient


    # wrap the reverse gradient as a Keras layer
    class GradientReversal (tf.keras.layers.Layer):

        def __init__(self, hp_lambda, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.hp_lambda = hp_lambda

        def call(self, inputs, training=None):
            return reverse_gradient(inputs, self.hp_lambda)

        def get_config(self):
            config = super().get_config()
            config['hp_lambda'] = self.hp_lambda
            return config

        @classmethod
        def from_config(cls, config):
            return cls(**config)


    # create domain classification model
    hp_lambda = tf.Variable(lamda)
    num_domains = 1 # 2: 'source' vs. 'target' (maybe not what we need), 1: prob. to be more or less 'source'-like

    domain1_preds_head_name = 'domain1_preds'
    domain1_preds = GradientReversal(hp_lambda)(hidden3)
    print("check: ",domain1_preds)
    domain1_preds = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='linear')(domain1_preds)
    domain1_preds = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='linear', name="do5")(domain1_preds)
    domain1_preds = tf.keras.layers.Activation("elu", name="do6")(domain1_preds)
    domain1_preds = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(domain1_preds)
    domain1_preds = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_domains, activation='softmax', name=domain1_preds_head_name)(domain1_preds)
    domain_classification_model1 = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=domain1_preds)

    # build a combined model
    combined_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[label_preds, domain1_preds])

    combined_model.compile(
                       optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                       loss={
                           label_preds_head_name:   'binary_crossentropy',
                           domain1_preds_head_name: 'binary_crossentropy'},
                       loss_weights={
                           label_preds_head_name:   1,
                           domain1_preds_head_name: 1},
                       metrics={ # weighted_metrics ?
                           label_preds_head_name:   ['AUC',lr_metric],
                           domain1_preds_head_name: ['AUC',lr_metric]}
                       )

    combined_model.summary()
    
    # training dataset
    nominal_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train0, y_train0))
    nominal_dataset = nominal_dataset.batch(int(batch_size/2))
    #domain1_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_target_for_train)
    domain1_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train1, y_train1))
    domain1_dataset = domain1_dataset.batch(int(batch_size/2))
    training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((nominal_dataset, domain1_dataset))

    # 'images' - coordinates in the phase spase.
    def _prepare_data_for_dann_training(nominal_data, domain1_data,
                                    main_head_name='main_preds', domain1_head_name='domain_preds'):

        nominal_images, nominal_labels = nominal_data
        domain1_images, domain1_labels = domain1_data

        num_nominal = tf.shape(nominal_images)[0]
        num_domain1 = tf.shape(domain1_images)[0]

        batch_images = tf.concat((nominal_images, domain1_images), axis=0)
        batch_labels = tf.concat((nominal_labels, domain1_labels), axis=0)
        batch_labels = tf.cast(batch_labels, dtype=tf.float32)
    
        # not to penalize the model for its prediscions on the domain images,
        # by assigning a weight = 0 to these elements of the batch:
        nominal_weight_per_sample = tf.tile([1.], [num_nominal])
        domain1_weight_per_sample = tf.tile([0.], [num_domain1])
        batch_sample_weights = tf.concat((nominal_weight_per_sample, domain1_weight_per_sample), axis=0)
    
        # domain classifiscation
        # we prepared ydn_train and yd1_train to be as what we need here
        # but it is simpler to reuse batch_sample_weights that passing extra argument to the function
        domain1_labels = batch_sample_weights
        domain1_sample_weights = tf.tile([1.], [num_nominal + num_domain1])

        batch_domain1 = {main_head_name: batch_labels,
                         domain1_head_name: domain1_labels}
        batch_sample_weights = {main_head_name: batch_sample_weights,
                            domain1_head_name: domain1_sample_weights}

        return batch_images, batch_domain1, batch_sample_weights


    import functools


    prepare_for_dann_training_fn = functools.partial(_prepare_data_for_dann_training,
                                                 main_head_name=label_preds_head_name,
                                                 domain1_head_name=domain1_preds_head_name)

    training_dataset = training_dataset.map(prepare_for_dann_training_fn, num_parallel_calls=4)
    print("training_dataset:",training_dataset)


    # testing dataset
    testing_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test1, y_test1))
    testing_dataset = testing_dataset.batch(batch_size)

    def _prepare_data_for_dann_testing(domain1_images, domain1_labels,
                                      main_head_name='main_preds', domain1_head_name='domain_preds'):
        # the batch contains only validation/test images from the target domain. 
        # this time, we want to evaluate the main loss over these images, so we assign a normal loss
        # weight = 1 to each samples.
        num_samples = tf.shape(domain1_images)[0]

        # want to evaluate over
        loss_weights = tf.tile([1], [num_samples])
        loss_weights = tf.cast(loss_weights, dtype=tf.float32)
        # to assure we have labels as zeroes
        domain1_labels = tf.tile([0], [num_samples])
        domain1_labels = tf.cast(domain1_labels, dtype=tf.float32)
        batch_targets = {main_head_name: domain1_labels,
                     domain1_head_name: domain1_labels}
        batch_sample_weights = {main_head_name: loss_weights,
                            domain1_head_name: loss_weights}

        return domain1_images, batch_targets, batch_sample_weights


    prepare_for_dann_testing_fn = functools.partial(_prepare_data_for_dann_testing,
                                                main_head_name=label_preds_head_name,
                                                domain1_head_name=domain1_preds_head_name)

    testing_dataset = testing_dataset.map(prepare_for_dann_testing_fn, num_parallel_calls=4)
    print("testing_dataset:",testing_dataset)
    
    metrics_to_print = collections.OrderedDict([
        # ("comb-loss", "loss"), 
        ("c-loss", label_preds_head_name + "_loss"),
        ("d-loss", domain1_preds_head_name + "_loss"), 
        ("c-acc", label_preds_head_name + "_acc"),
        ("d-acc", domain1_preds_head_name + "_acc"),
        ("target c-acc", "val_" + label_preds_head_name + "_acc"),
        # ("target d-acc", "val_" + domain_preds_head_name + "_acc")
    ])
    from keras_custom_callbacks import SimpleLogCallback
    callbacks = [
        # Callback to simply log metrics at the end of each epoch (saving space compared to verbose=1/2):
        SimpleLogCallback(metrics_to_print, num_epochs=num_epoch, log_frequency=1)]

    history = combined_model.fit(
        training_dataset, epochs=num_epoch, #steps_per_epoch=train_steps_per_epoch,
        #validation_data=testing_dataset, #validation_steps=test_steps_per_epoch,
         callbacks=callbacks)
    return label_prediction_model,combined_model,nom_fit,d1_as_nom_fit,history
```

I converted all tensor dtypes of training and testing set into float32, as the output displayed below, but still got a warning about int32. I have no ideas about where it comes from.

```
training_dataset: <ParallelMapDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 17), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), {'label_preds': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), 'domain1_preds': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)}, {'label_preds': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), 'domain1_preds': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)})>
testing_dataset: <ParallelMapDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 17), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), {'label_preds': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), 'domain1_preds': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)}, {'label_preds': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), 'domain1_preds': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)})>
Training: start.
WARNING:tensorflow:The dtype of the source tensor must be floating (e.g. tf.float32) when calling GradientTape.gradient, got tf.int32
```

Could anyone give a help? Thank you in advance!